# Are GET variables proserved in the URL when a form is POSTed?

Tags: php, html, forms

I tried searching but didn't see an answer to this question. Here is a simple form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="1">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I put that code into `test.html` and browsed to:

```
/test.html?test=test
```

After submitting the form, the variable `test` is still in the URL. I thought the form being submitted would wipe out the GET parameter, but it didn't.

Do all browsers exhibit this behavior, or is this something specific to FireFox?

Comment: FYI you can send POST and GET requests at the same time.

Comment: its because you have a blank action, which is a bad idea. the browser use s the 'current' page when the action is not set.

Comment: @HamZa no you cant, but you can have a query string in the url with a post request

Comment: @Dagon No it's not, it is a clearly-defined case that submits to the form to the current URL.

Comment: @Musa If I wrote `<form action="script.php?foo=bar" method="post">` I would send a GET request *and* a post request :)

Comment: @HamZa No, you would send a POST request with GET parameters in the url.

Comment: @Kolink, whats 'not'? a bad idea? or the use of the current page if action is blank?

Comment: @Kolink Copy paste [this](http://codepad.org/aJkdGnTm) and try it out.

Comment: @HamZa Okay, so I get `$_GET` variables and `$_POST` variables. But `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` very clearly states `POST`.

Comment: @HamZa kolink is just being particular about the language, only one *request* is sent

Comment: Deceze clears this up !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"POST" and "GET" parameters are quite a misnomer in PHP. URLs can have *query parameters*, regardless of the type of request. A POST request can have *request body data*. URL query parameters end up in `$_GET` in PHP, URL encoded body data of POST requests in `$_POST`. There really isn't such a thing as "GET parameters" outside of PHP "`$_GET`" nomenclature.

Forms without a specified action submit to the current *URL*, including any *URL query parameters*.

Hope that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

A form with `method="get"` will overwrite any existing GET parameters with the new ones. However, a form with `method="post"` will preserve them.

If you want to remove them manually, try `action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"` (or for PHP 5.3 and below: `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"`)

Comment: In PHP5.4+ short echo tags are supported everywhere regardless of shorttags settings correct?